# Probablity of an event NOT in the sample space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a simple question that boils down to the basic definitions of probablity.
We could define probablity of an event A, denoted as `P(A)`, as the ratio of the number of favorable outcomes to the total number of possible outcomes in the sample space.
Sample space is a collection or a set of possible outcomes of an experiment.

Now, assume that I ask what is probablity of me getting the number `7` when I roll a dice. Now, this should be an impossible event with probablity being `0` since it can never happen on a fair dice. However, the event of getting `7` is **not** included in the sample space, so how can we even define such a probablity? What is the correct answer and explaination to defining the probablity of an such event?

P.S, Sorry if this question seems basic but my professor asked me this and it kind of left me confused, so I'm asking this here for some clarity on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event is defined as a subset of a sample space. If the sample space is $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, then $\{7\}$ is not an event (because $\{7\}\not\subseteq S$) and its probability is not defined. You can model the situation as the empty set $\{\}$ because the outcome you are interested in is not an element of $S$. Since the empty set is a subset of $S$, then its probability is defined and is zero.

Comment: thanks for the response! but i am not sure i understand how the event of getting 7 can be modelled as an empty set?

Comment: If you get a 7, then that means you did not get a 1, a 2, a 3, a 4, a 5, or a 6.

Comment: @woka It could also be understood this way: the value of rolling a dice can be understood as a function from the sample space to the considered outcomes. In this case, since the sample space already consists of the outcomes of rolling the dice, it can just be understood as the identity function $X$ on $S = \{1, \cdots, 6\}$. Then the event of rolling a $7$ can be understood as the set $\{s \in S: X(s) = 7\}$, which is indeed the empty set.